# how to hide/show using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have menu having different categories each categories having different sections.If  when i click on section one category the related section  should be show and reaming sections should be hide. I don't want more code need to reduce lines of code please any one help me

my html code

```
 <ul>
  <li><a class="cat_1" href="#home" onclick="category(1)">Section One</a></li>
  <li><a class="cat_2" href="#news" onclick="category(2)">Section Two</a></li>
  <li><a class="cat_3" href="#contact" onclick="category(3)">Section three</a></li>
  <li><a class="cat_4" href="#about" onclick="category(4)">Section four</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="subcat_1" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section One</h1>
  <p>Section One</p>
</div>

<div class="subcat_2" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section Two</h1>
  <p>Section Two</p>
  <p>Section Two</p>
  <p>Section Two</p>
  <p>Section Two</p>
</div>

<div class="subcat_2" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section Two</h1>
  <p>Section Two</p>
</div>

<div class="subcat_3" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section three</h1>
  <p>Section three</p>
</div>
<div class="subcat_4" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section four</h1>
  <p>Section four</p>
</div>
<div class="subcat_4" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section four</h1>
  <p>Section four</p>
</div>
```

Jquery code

```
function category(val){
    $(".subcat_"+ val).show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide all using [`Attribute Starts With Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) before showing the specific section:

```js
function category(val){
  $("[class^=subcat_").hide();
  $(".subcat_"+ val).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="cat_1" href="#home" onclick="category(1)">Section One</a></li>
  <li><a class="cat_2" href="#news" onclick="category(2)">Section Two</a></li>
  <li><a class="cat_3" href="#contact" onclick="category(3)">Section three</a></li>
  <li><a class="cat_4" href="#about" onclick="category(4)">Section four</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="subcat_1" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section One</h1>
  <p>Section One</p>
</div>

<div class="subcat_2" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section Two</h1>
  <p>Section Two</p>
  <p>Section Two</p>
  <p>Section Two</p>
  <p>Section Two</p>
</div>

<div class="subcat_2" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section Two</h1>
  <p>Section Two</p>
</div>

<div class="subcat_3" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section three</h1>
  <p>Section three</p>
</div>
<div class="subcat_4" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section four</h1>
  <p>Section four</p>
</div>
<div class="subcat_4" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section four</h1>
  <p>Section four</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much you are saved my time it's perfect work as i am expected once again thanks Mamun

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$(".subcat_"+ val).toggle();
```

?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the css property with Jquery.

So:

```
$(".subcat_"+ val).css("display", "block");
```

Something like this?
You will have to set it back to `.css("display", "none")` in the other functions though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for show/hide section

```
function category(val){
    $(".subcat_"+ val).show();
    $("div[class^='subcat_']").each(function(index, item){
       //console.log(1)
       if(!$(this).hasClass("subcat_"+ val)){
          $(this).hide();
       }
    })
}
```

```js
function category(val){
    $(".subcat_"+ val).show();
    $("div[class^='subcat_']").each(function(index, item){
       //console.log(1)
       if(!$(this).hasClass("subcat_"+ val)){
          $(this).hide();
       }
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="cat_1" href="#home" onclick="category(1)">Section One</a></li>
  <li><a class="cat_2" href="#news" onclick="category(2)">Section Two</a></li>
  <li><a class="cat_3" href="#contact" onclick="category(3)">Section three</a></li>
  <li><a class="cat_4" href="#about" onclick="category(4)">Section four</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="subcat_1" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section One</h1>
  <p>Section One</p>
</div>

<div class="subcat_2" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section Two</h1>
  <p>Section Two</p>
  <p>Section Two</p>
  <p>Section Two</p>
  <p>Section Two</p>
</div>

<div class="subcat_2" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section Two</h1>
  <p>Section Two</p>
</div>

<div class="subcat_3" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section three</h1>
  <p>Section three</p>
</div>
<div class="subcat_4" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section four</h1>
  <p>Section four</p>
</div>
<div class="subcat_4" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Section four</h1>
  <p>Section four</p>
</div>
```